# Python urllib3 - Crawling webpages failed at a specific webpage only from google cloud vm

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, urllib3

I have built a crawler script that download webpages using urllib3 and python3. I ran the crawler in a `Google Cloud Virtual Machine` instance and tried it with many different urls. I found a url that i couldn't download on the VM instance but succeeded to download on my personal Linux.

The code that i've tried on my computer and worked:

```
>>> import urllib3
>>> pool = urllib3.PoolManager()
>>> response = pool.request('GET', 'http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/drake/dowhatyoudo.html')
>>> response.status
200
```

I have tried the exact same code on the VM instance using ssh and this exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 594, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 391, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 2, in raise_from
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 387, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1197, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 297, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 266, in _read_status
    raise RemoteDisconnected("Remote end closed connection without"
http.client.RemoteDisconnected: Remote end closed connection without response
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/urllib3/request.py", line 66, in request
    **urlopen_kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/urllib3/request.py", line 87, in request_encode_url
    return self.urlopen(method, url, **extra_kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/urllib3/poolmanager.py", line 244, in urlopen
    response = conn.urlopen(method, u.request_uri, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 671, in urlopen
    release_conn=release_conn, **response_kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 671, in urlopen
    release_conn=release_conn, **response_kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 671, in urlopen
    release_conn=release_conn, **response_kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 643, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 303, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='www.azlyrics.com', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /lyrics/drake/dowhatyoudo.html (Caused by ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote
 end closed connection without response',)))
```

I have checked the VM dashboard and I didn't find any firewall or other restrictions that I may have mistakenly defined.

What could it possibly be?

Comment: A lot of websites block all requests from popular cloud services, specifically because they don't want to deal with bots crawling their websites. You'd probably get this same error if you ran your code from AWS.

Comment: Agreed, sounds like the server is throttling/blocking your requests.